# How can I select from multiple Submit button with same name (HtmlUnit, Java)

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am using HTMLUnit, and I have a problem. The webpage has multiple buttons and thay have same name, same class, the only difference is the onClick.

How can I click on my button? (When I run my code, there is nothing happened)

I need this button:

```html
<button name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-success" onClick="add();">Add</button>
```

But there is also in the same source code:

```html
<button name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-success" onClick="update();">Update</button>

<button name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-success" onClick="update2();">Update</button>
```

I tried to submit as usual, but nothing happened:
(I tried also as HtmlSubmitInput, but I've got a cast error)

```java
HtmlButton submitBtn = (HtmlButton) currentPage.getElementByName("singlebutton");
currentPage = (HtmlPage) submitBtn.click();
```

How can I reach the button what I need? It is not between

Thanks in advance

p.s.: if it is matter the button is nested in a DIV:

```html
<div class="tab-pane active fade in" id="add">
```

Comment: Should be possible to select the specific node by xpath.
http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomNode.html#getFirstByXPath-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparrently, you can make css-like selects on the DOM.

From the "Getting started" page of HtmlUnit:

```java
@Test
public void cssSelector() throws Exception {
    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net");

        //get list of all divs
        final DomNodeList<DomNode> divs = page.querySelectorAll("div");
        for (DomNode div : divs) {
            ....
        }

        //get div which has the id 'breadcrumbs'
        final DomNode div = page.querySelector("div#breadcrumbs");
    }
}
```

So you should be able to select:

```java
final DomNode element = page.querySelector("button.btn-success"
    + "[name='singlebutton'][onClick='add();']");
```

Or rather, if you feel safer selecting the button inside the div:

```java
final DomNode element = page.querySelector("div#add button.btn-success[name='singlebutton']");
```

Answer (score 0):

we can just create plain javascript functions add(), update() that will be called from the click of the button, instead of following it via DOM